# How to increase limit of concurrent EC2 instances running in a region?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudformation

I am trying to add three t2.small instances to single region, in this case us-east-2, but couldn't do so.

I could edit this question to tell you the precise error message if requested.

How do I increase this limit?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html "You can take the following steps to request an increase for limits. These increases are not granted immediately, so it may take a couple of days for your increase to become effective."

Comment: How much will  it cost me ,I am using  trying to deploy my own paas using convox.?

Comment: Costs nothing to raise the limit. The instances themselves will cost money, of course. The limit is mainly there to prevent you from doing something dumb, like accidentally launching a million of them.

Comment: If I run 10 t2.small say 75 hrs each in a month ,that's makes total 750 hrs will it cross free tier.

Comment: The free tier gives you 750 hours a month of `t2.micro` usage. Running `t2.small` instances will cost you money.

Comment: I mistyped micro to small.

Comment: You can run one t2.micro instance 750 hours or ten t2.micro instances 75 hours under free tier, assuming AWS will raise your limits that high.

Comment: Why not asking directly Amazon support for questions about their pricing and limits?

Answer (score 0):

As CeeJay said in comments (which should really be an answer) you simply request AWS increase the number of instances you can start in the region. The form is available from [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html). You typically have to tell them instance types and numbers.

AWS can take between two hours and a week to change your limit, in my experience. If you're an established customer who's been paying their bills it's likely easier.

There's no cost to increase your limits. The limits are in place to prevent new users running up large bills.

If you need more instances immediately you could try using different instance types. That might not work well for auto scaling, but you could do it manually for the few days it's likely to take AWS to change your limits.